How to optimize a view with dynamic pivot that takes too long when calling it with filter
I have a view call that takes 30 minutes when I'm calling the view like select * from PIVOTED_DATA where local_datetime>= '2024-06-13 00:00 and local_datetime<= '2024-06-13 01:00, but if inside a query I set  that condition, takes only 11 seconds.
This is the Plan for the 30 mins query
The view definition is this:
create or replace view PIVOTED_DATA as (
    with 
    long_format_data as(
        select
            src.local_datetime,
            src.tag_name,
            -- tag_description,
            src.VALUE_FLOAT
        from data_source as src
        where 
            company='Huggies'
            and tag_name in (
                select
                    tag_name
                from
                    master_tag_dictionary
                where
                    DIVISION = 'Sales'
            )
            
    ),
    pivot_data as (
        select *
        from long_format_data
        PIVOT (
                MAX(VALUE_FLOAT)
                FOR TAG_NAME IN (
                    ANY ORDER BY TAG_NAME
                )
                -- FOR tag_description IN (
                --     ANY ORDER BY tag_description
                -- )
            )
            order by 
                local_datetime desc
    )
    select 
        *
    from
        pivot_data
)
;

I tried to call a query directly and set a where clause inside long_format_data like
local_datetime>= '2024-06-13 00:00 and local_datetime<= '2024-06-13 01:00
the query only takes 11 seconds to return data. This is the Plan
What should I modify to the view to support that filtering first instead of probably filtering at the end?

Does the filtering predicate get placed at the same plan location when running in the view compared to runnig on the plain tables? Compare both query plans.

Change your view to a stored procedure and pass in the criteria

@TheImpaler it is in the same plan location. I checked that with Explain and in the Query Profile.

@BartMcEndree I could do that, but I need to use that view for Dataflow from PowerBI and need that view

Hi can you send the plan details when running from the View and from the table.

The local_datetime predicate can’t be pushed down past the pivot. Are you able to write this without the pivot?

@HimanshuKandpal The question was updated with the images. Even for the explain took too long

@Teej The Pivot could be better. In Dataflow PowerBI takes too long in long format

I'd consider moving the view to a dynamic table, so that it becomes materialized and you can cluster it, which will then act a lot more like a persistent table.  They have some limitations and pivots might force a total refresh rather than incremental updates, so keep your eyes on costs.

Please send the query id to support, as this is something that the eng teams would be interested in optimizing (especially as dynamic pivots are a new feature and this is an edge case)

Hi @FelipeHoffa, this is the query_id 01b50eca-0202-5d06-0000-640477579f5f for the 11 seconds query and 01b4fbd0-0202-5b41-0000-64047377b78b for the 30 mins query

I can't look at query ids, only at reproduceable questions. For query ids, please contact support
